# Python Server to Server communication, multi-threading, Consumer Producer

Tags: python, multithreading, http, network-programming, server-to-server

I want to use python to create two web servers which communicates over HTTP protocol between them. First web server is producer which produces some data on multiple threads (more than 5) and it sends these data from multiple threads to the second web server. Second server is consumer, which receives and consumes data from first server and populates shared resources, a queue
or stack with received data. Second server also has multiple threads which extracts one element from shared resource and is sending that extracted data element from second server to the first. Can you suggest me any code samples or logic templates for such kind of task?

Comment: Is it possible you could clarify if there can be a clear client-server relationship between your two servers? For example, when the second server sends the 'extracted data element' to the first, is that in response to a request from the first server? Or must they both act as both a client (sending requests to the other server) and a server (responding to requests from the other server)?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.